# Top analysis in Stacked Bar chart

Tags: spotfire, stacked-chart

i need support in creating Top 3 Values in Stacked Bar chart.i have attached image of chart how it need to look for your reference.

[image: Report Format]

Comment: Can you elaborate? These aren't the top 3, they are merely a coloring option. What is your aggregation method? Is it still Sum([Sales Values])

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show the top 10 column values in Spotfire](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787828/how-to-show-the-top-10-column-values-in-spotfire)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spotfire - Show top values in stacked bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439011/spotfire-show-top-values-in-stacked-bar-chart)