# Spotfire - Show top values in stacked bar chart

Tags: bar-chart, spotfire, tibco, stacked, stackedbarseries

I have a stacked bar chart that looks like this :

[image: Example of data]

I would like to only show the top 3 bars in terms of value, that is to say the three first bars. I tried to use the Show/Hide feature but it doesn't work as I expected.

For example if I limit to Show top 1 value with the Show/Hide value, i get :

[image: Bug example]

when I expect to also have the orange and blue bars that are stacked in the first picture.

Is there a way to do what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way to do this :

Using the Show/Hide rules of the properties of the visualization, you have to add this rule

```
DenseRank(Sum([Value]) over (All([Axis.Color])),"desc") <= 3
```

Then you have to `[Axis.Value]` in the value input.

---

`3` is the number of bars to have in the bar chart.

`[Value]` is the column of the Y Axis, in my case I used Count() because my Y axis is `(Row Count)`.

---

You can find more info at this link : https://community.tibco.com/questions/question-showhide-top-10

Answer (score 1):

You will have to achieve a dynamic rank and use that to filter out the top 3. Put this rank logic in the hide/show. 
It's not clearly given here but in ur dataset you can rank by column on x axis and say rank always less than 3.